# crc32 hash default/invalid value?

Tags: c++, c, crc32

I am building a simple string ID system using crc32 to generate 32 bit integer handles from my strings. I'd like to default the hash inside my StringID wrapper class to an invalid index by default, **is there a value that crc32 will never generate?** Will I have to use a separate flag?

**Clarification:** I am not interested in language specific answers. *I'd simply like to know if there is an integer outside of the crc32 range that can be used to represent an unhashed value*.

Thanks!

Comment: What programming language are you using? Why do you need to default the hash at all?

Comment: I am using c++ (but I don't think that is relevant for the nature of this question). What I want is a way to identify if a StringID is default constructed (hence empty, nothing hashed) or actually contains a valid hash.

Comment: The language is relevant because e.g. in Perl you could just set it to `undef` or even create an object without that particular attribute (and maybe mark the attribute as `lazy` so it gets created on demand). But why does your `StringID` have a default constructor? And why is it a class in the first place?

Comment: @melpomene the pearl example makes sense. It is a class because it provides ways of retrieving the original string, hiding away implementation specific  logic etc. The question really is: Is there an integer value that can be used to represent that (i.e. a value out of the range of crc32). I will update the question to clarify that.

Comment: crc32 can generate every single possible 32-bit value, sorry.

Comment: @MarkRansom thanks, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: Since the answer is no, and since it could cover the range of 32-bit integers, perhaps you could use a 64 bit integer to hold the result, and anything over std::numeric_limits<int>::max()  is your non-valid "result".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a value that crc32 will never generate?

No, it will generate any/all values in the range of a 32-bit integer.

> Will I have to use a separate flag?

Not necessarily.

If you decide that (e.g.) 0x00000000 means "CRC not set" and non-zero is the CRC value; then after calculating the CRC (but before storing it or checking the stored value) you can do `if(CRCvalue == 0) CRCvalue = 0xFFFFFFFF;`.

This weakens the CRC by an extremely tiny amount. Specifically, for 2 random pieces of data, for pure CRC32 there's 1 chance in 4294967296 of the CRCs matching, and with "zero means unset" there's 1 chance in 4294967295.000000000232830643654 of the CRCs matching.

Answer (score 0):

No. A CRC-32 can be *any* 32-bit value. You'll need to indicate an invalid index somewhere else.

My [spoof code](https://github.com/madler/spoof) allows you to choose bit locations in a message to modify and the desired CRC, and will solve for which of those locations to flip to get exactly that CRC.

Comment: some reasoning would make you more trustworthy :)

Comment: @LuisColorado https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18431/range-of-crc-32

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy demonstration to the fact that you can generate any crc32 value, as it is de division mod P (where P is the generator polynomial) in a galois field (which happens to be a field, as real or complex numbers are), you can subtract (this is a XOR operation, so adding and subtracting are indeed the same thing) to your polynomial its modulus, giving a 0 remainder, then you can add to this multiple of the modulus any of all the possible crc32 values to it (as they are already remainders of divisions, their crc32 is just themselves) to get any of the 2^32 possible values.

It is a common practice to add as many zero bits as necessary to complete a full 32 bit word (this appears as a multiplication by a constant value `x^32`), and then subtract(xor) the remainder to that, making the result a multiple of of the modulus (remember that the addition and subtraction are the same ---a xor operation) and so making the `crc32(pol) = 0x0000;`

## edit(easier to see)

Indeed, each of the possible 2^32 values for crc32, when divided by the generator polynomial, give themselves as a result (they are coprime with the generator polynomial, as are the numbers 1 .. N when doing arithmetic modulo N on integers) *so they all are possible results* of the `crc32()` operator.

The crc operation, as implemented in many places, is not that simple... as some implementations initialize the remainder register as `0xffffffff` and look for `0xffffffff` at termination(indeed, crc32 does this).... If you do the maths, you'll guess the reason for that:  Initializing the register to `0x11111111` is equivalent to having a previous remainder of `0xffffffff` in a longer string... and looking for `0xffffffff` at the end is like appending `0xffffffff` to the original string.  This has the effect of concatenating the bit string `0xffffffff` before and after your string, making the remainder sensible to appends of a string of zeros *before and after* the crc32 calculated string (altering the string of bits by appending zeros at either side).  Anyway, this modification doesn't alter the original algorithm of calculating a polynomial remainder, so any of the `2**32` values are possible also in this case.